# Simple line-by-line read in Java

Tags: java, file, io

I have input of the format:

```
12 : 13 24 1 2
2 : 1 4
9 : 0 1 82
...
```

I want to read in each line as a StringStream, and then later read through each StringStream piece by piece.

> For example, line 1 would be stored as a StringStream "12 : 13 24 1
>   2", and then I could just read it in piece by piece ("12", ":", "13",
>   "24", "1", "2") (something like cin >> stingstream in C++).

What's the best way to do this in Java?

Comment: Take a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/), [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) and [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are trying to do is called tokenizing :)

```
// pretty standard open file with buffered reader.
File           file               = new File("inputFileName");
FileReader     fileReader         = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader bufferedFileReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

// The string that will hold the content of each line.
String line;

// Read each line and store string content in line.
while((line=bufferedFileReader.readLine())!=null)
{
   // Create a tokenizer to split the string into tokens.
   StringTokenizer tokenizedLine= new StringTokenizer(line);

   // For each token in the current line so something
   while (while (tokenizedLine.hasMoreTokens()) 
   {
         System.out.println(tokenizedLine.nextToken());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader.readLine()` to read lines, then `java.util.Scanner` to carve up each line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BufferedReader class to read line content.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("c:\\text.txt")));
```

Use **br.readLine()** to read content line by line.

Comment: what about from the console?

Comment: You can use java.util.Scanner, like java.util.Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); and use scanner.nextLine() to get what you try to input from Console

Answer (score 0):

```
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File("sample.txt"));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String str;
    while((str=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

After reading the line you can use `split()` on `:` and subsequently by ' ' (space). You will get the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a bit different than C++ in this respect.  The Java InputStream reads/writes things at the byte level, and Java Reader classes read/write at the character level.  Given your example, you should select one of the Reader classes, such as java.io.StringReader for things in String form in memory or for input data in a file use FileReader.  There are several choices for Readers (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)

Unless you want to look for the newline separators yourself, you can combine one of the above readers with the java.io.BufferedReader to read one line at a time with the readLine() method. There is an example in the Javadocs for BufferedReader for using it with a FileReader.